# how to bind and use textbox in RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

i have a RadGrid and i want some textBox inside RadGrid For insert Data How i can do this?

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="First" HeaderText="LastName">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                           </ItemTemplate>
           </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="LastName" HeaderText="LastName">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                               </ItemTemplate>
               </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

this is my textBox inside of RadGrid and i not sure it's best way for this, please help me for use each of TextBoxes  i don't know how to get value from each textboxes in code behind and that work for creat textbox in gird is correct or not .
i have 11 static rows and 6 field at all , thanks for help

```
foreach (GridDataItem Dataitem in RIV_RateHireGrid.Items)
       {
            ???
       }
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @LajosArpad 2 problem, i don't know how to get data from each textboxes in code behind and that work for creat textbox in gird is correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik has a good documentation. There a a lot of ways to accomplish that. And there are small differences (using inplace edit / form edit etc...)

[How to use Custom Templates with RadGrid](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/custom-edit-forms)

Here you can find also a good Documentation about accessing those values.

[How to access Template Values](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows)

So the answer is RTFM :)